# Ocultar foto do perfil do usuário do Google do site quando tiver logado

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, google-maps

Boa tarde, estou fazendo um site para uma cliente, ele tem interação com a api Google Maps plataform, quando o usuário está logado na sua conta do google fica aparecendo a foto dele no maps, a minha cliente gostaria que desativasse isso, eu expliquei que só a pessoa consegui vê e tudo, mas por ser um site restrito ela gostaria disso desativado. Gostaria de saber se tem como desativar isso por meio de código no wordpress.   Segue abaixo a foto do mapa com a foto de perfil. Obrigada desde já. [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: A classe da imagem é a `profile-photo profile-photo-light` mas acho pouco provável que vc consiga altera-la, pois ela está dentro do iframe... Uma gambiarra seria cortar a lateral direita do iframe até a imagem sumir

Comment: Procure na documentação da API. Com certeza ensina como desabilitar. [Aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29125321/how-to-hide-the-sign-in-button-from-google-maps) mostra como ocultar o botão de  `sign in`.